# How to stop text being centered in HTML input box?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a big input box for the message in my contact form. On single-line text boxes, it works fine, but if you start to make it have multiple lines like the example, it always has the input in the middle.

```html
<input type="text" style="width: 700px; height: 200px; font-size: 20px;" name="message" placeholder="Message" />
```

The text is vertically-centered. How can I change this? Thanks, Yankue.

Comment: could you please post a MWE

Comment: ahh so you want it bottom centered

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `<textarea>`

```html
<textarea type="text" style="width: 700px; height: 200px; font-size: 20px;" name="message" placeholder="Message" >
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `<textarea>` is probably the better option if you're going for a large body of text.